# Compare two tables on screen using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to compare two tables as a QA. I am extracting values of the both using the following code in Selenium.

FYI: I have used two different browser windows and different variable names for each of the two tables (i.e. one in each environment)

```
String first_part = ".//*[@id='Matrix']/tbody/tr[";
    String second_part = "]/td[";
    String third_part = "]/a";


    //rows of the matrix table (Always 7)
    for (int i=4; i<=7; i++){
        //Columns of the matrix table (Always 4)
        for (int j=1; j<=4; j++){
            //Prepare final xpath for each cell value
            String matrix_cell_path =   first_part+i+second_part+j+third_part;
                //Retrieve cell-value
                String matrix_cell_data= driver.findElement(By.xpath(matrix_cell_path)).getText();
                System.out.print("matrix_cell_data["+i+"]["+j+"]= "+matrix_cell_data + " ");
        }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");  
    }


    String first_part_Prod = ".//*[@id='Matrix']/tbody/tr[";
    String second_part_Prod = "]/td[";
    String third_part_Prod = "]/a";

    //rows of the matrix table (Always 7)
    for (int k=4; k<=7; k++){
        //Columns of the matrix table (Always 4)
        for (int l=1; l<=4; l++){
            //Prepare final xpath for each cell value
            String matrix_cell_path_Prod = first_part_Prod+k+second_part_Prod+l+third_part_Prod;
                //Retrieve cell-value
                String matrix_cell_data_Prod = second_driver.findElement(By.xpath(matrix_cell_path_Prod)).getText();
                System.out.print("matrix_cell_data_Prod["+k+"]["+l+"]= "+matrix_cell_data_Prod + " ");
        }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");  
    }
```

I want to verify if each cell in both the tables are equal. how to do it?

I have used the following check, but shows error:

**matrix_cell_data cannot be resolved to a variable.**

```
   //Matrix Data - Content Check:
    try {
        matrix_cell_data = matrix_cell_data_Prod;
        System.out.println("Great");
    }catch (Exception ex2){
        System.out.println("Exception"+ex2);
    }
```

Comment: Both the variables are defined inside a for loop, so the visibility is restricted to inside each iteration of the loop. Store the values in a two dimensional array if you want to refer to the position of the values and then compare the two arrays. Or else use a list to store and compare

Comment: An easy way would be to append each cell in string builder. Then compare the strings to get the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by first creating a class, say MyMatrixData that implements Comparable on itself

```
public class MyMatrixData implements Comparable<MyMatrixData> {
   private String columnOneName;
   private String columnTwoName;
   private String columnNName;
   //With getters and setters (not shown)

   @Override
   public int compareTo(MyMatrixData actualData) {
      assertEquals("Some helpful text", this.getColumnOneName(), actualData.getColumnOneName());
      assertEquals("Some helpful text", this.getColumnTwoName(), actualData.getColumnTwoName());
      assertEquals("Some helpful text", this.getColumnNName(), actualData.getColumnNName());

      return 0;
   }
}
```

Next I create a feature file with steps that cause the actual data to be displayed on the page. This is followed by a step that gets the actual data from the table and compares it to expected.  Something like:

```
Feature: Compare expected MatrixData to actual

Scenario: Some data driven or choice driven test
   Given user "me" logs in to the Matrix system
   When I navigate to the page that displays MatrixData
   Then the displayed MatrixData matches the expected
     | columnOneName | columnTwoName | columnNName |
     | Killroy       | was           | here        |
     | Betty Bop     | was           | too         |
```

The step definition might look like

```
@Then ("^the displayed MatrixData matches the expected$)
public void the_displayed_matrixdata_matches_expected(List<MyMatrixData> expectedData) throws Throwable {
    for (int i=1;i<expectedData.size(),i++) {
      MyMatrixData actualMatrixRow = new MyMatrixData();
      actualMatrixRow.setColumnOneName(aPageObject.getColumnOneName(i));
      actualMatrixRow.setColumnTwoName(aPageObject.getColumnTwoName(i));
      actualMatrixRow.setColumnNName(aPageObject.getColumnNName(i));

      assertEquals("helpful msg", 0, expectedData.get(i).compareTo(actualMatrixRow));
    }
}
```

I left the page object methods to get the data from the HTML as an exercise. I usually also create a page object method to get the actual number of rows so that I can compare that to the expected number of rows. Also left as an exercise. :-)  You may notice that a 0 is returned only if all the asserts in compareTo pass.  The assertion in the step def is more documentation then anything else.

I use this pattern over and over. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: If you have no predetermined expected results you can pick one of the actual displayed data to be expected and compare the other actual to it.   The logic is much the same.